# Absolute value theorem for sequences

Tags: sequences-and-series

In the proof for this theorem, my textbook states:

$$-|a_n|\le a_n\le |a_n|$$ for all n.

And uses this as the basis for the rest of the proof.

However, I cannot seem to get the intuition. For instance, $a_n =2n$, then when $n=1$, $a_2= 2$.

But by that inequality, we have:

$$-|2| \le 2 \le |2|$$

Which doesn't make much sense to me.

Which part did I go wrong?

Comment: Why does it make no sense?

Comment: Actually, *any real number $x$ is either $|x|$ (if it is non-negative) or $-|x|$ (if it is non-positive).

Comment: @BadAtGeometry because $-|2| = -2$ (right?) so it can not satisfy $-|2| \le 2$

Comment: $-2 \le 2$ is certainly satisfied. $-|x| \le x \le |x|$ holds for all real numbers $x$.

Comment: @MartinR I'm not quite sure how it can satisfy the equal part though. Less than, certainly, but not equal to.

Comment: What do you mean by ”satisfy"? $a \le b$ means $a< b$ **or** $a = b$.

Comment: It doesn't satisfy both inequality and equality simultaneously. That is why we say $x$ is less than **or** equal to $|x|$.

Answer (score 1):

There is actually nothing wrong. $-|2| \le 2 \le |2| \Rightarrow -2 \le 2 \le 2 \checkmark$.